# imageview background is not filling to its boundaries

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image view.. I have provided both background and foreground images in the image view.. but the background image is not stretching completely to the imageview's boundary..

**so question is how to remove that space?**

this is the stretched image with imageview grid 
[image]

this is the imageview without the padding 
[image]

the code for the imageview is provided below

```
     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_targets_distributor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_ring"

        android:padding="45dp"  <-- when u change this to 0 you get second image
        android:src="@drawable/selector_dist" />
```

now selector_ring consist of links to two  xmls where the ring is an layout as provided below

```
 <item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="10dp"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <solid android:color="#01b1ec" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="5dp"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <solid android:color="#eceaea" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="1dp"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and when src image --> selector_dist <-- , is removed the gap btw the ring and imageview border still remains..

**so question is how to remove that space?**

Comment: Use oval shape instead.

Comment: @corsair992  thank you for the suggestion could you post it as an answer so as to vote you..

Comment: Eh, not worth it to post an answer, this is too trivial.

Comment: maybe use scaletype="fitXY"?